# Is there a way to make Adium open links with Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, adium

When someone sends me a link in `Adium` I'll click it and Safari will open up. I'd like links to be opened by Google Chrome instead.

I've had a look around the web and in the preferences but for the the life of me I can't figure this simple one out.

Any clues?

NB: My default browser is Google Chrome.

**EDIT**

I'm running version 1.4.1 (i.e. up-to-date). I use this [SkypePlugin](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=5011). Apart from that it's plain vanilla `Adium`.

Comment: It's an obvious question, but, is Google Chrome your default browser?

Comment: Yeh it is. Sorry I'll update my question.

Comment: Does it happen with other app, too? Like Mail. I don't have a Mac right now, but could you try to open TextEdit, insert a link, wait for it to be detected (line return should do), click on it and see which browser is open?

Comment: After some googling, I found Filevault might be a culprit, is it enabled?

Comment: @Loic: I don't use Mail but TextEdit and Terminal open links in Google Chrome. I'm pretty sure all my apps do except Adium. I don't have FileVault enabled.

Comment: Any Adium extension installed?

Comment: @Loic: Just the SkypePlugin. Do you think that could be the cause?

Comment: I don't use it and don't know what it does, but just in case, disabled/uninstall it, and then test if the links work correctly.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it doesn't seem SkypePlugin temper with the incoming messages. But it doesn't hurt to temporarily remove it.

Comment: Some other basic questions: do you use themes to display your messages? Are you up to date?

Comment: @Loic: It basically allows Adium to hook into Skype. I'll disable it and report back. Just gonna grab a bite to eat first. Thanks for your help with this. :)

Comment: @Loic: Thank you dear sir. It appears there's some type of bug with the [SkypePlugin](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=5011) that causes this behaviour. It's a shame because it's a useful plugin for me. Oh well. I'll accept an answer from you if you care to write one up. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable the Skype plugin, it must be tempering with the way Adium handles URLs opening.

Comment: Thanks very much Loic. After uninstalling the [SkypePlugin](http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=xtras&xtra_id=5011) everything is working as it should.